# Cron job to check date in a database and send a notification

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, cron, reminders

I have a user who will input the date for the next event. It is saved in the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss (eg: 2013-06-09 00:00:00) in a MySQL database. How can I write a cron job that sends a notification to the user 3 days in advance about an upcoming event?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this in two steps:

1. You have to write a PHP script that checks in your database if there
   is an event coming up three days from now and if so, which user in your
   database created that event. If there's an event, the script sends a
   reminder email to the user.
2. In cron you create a task that runs the above mentioned script once
   a day.

Now that you know the steps, please try to figure out the implementation yourself.